# Place a Flash file (.swf) in GSP page-Grails

Tags: html, flash, grails

I need to include flash file in my grails app,in my view page.
Need some code regarding it.

Thanks in advance
Bhanu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use html object tag in your GSP

```
<object width="300" height="120" codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0">
  <embed src="path-to-swf-file" width="400" height="40"></embed>
</object>
```